# Android - Center View in Other View inside Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Hi I am having trouble centering my text view in an image view. I want it to look kinda like this but have it actually vertically centered and stay vertically centered if the the font size changes.

[image]

And here is what I have in XML I don't care if I need to change the relative layout to another kind that doesn't matter to me I just want to be able to center this. Heres the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.spencer.app.ProfileActivity"
android:id="@+id/layout">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="140dp"
    android:minWidth="140dp"
    android:id="@+id/logoBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_useless"
    android:background="#ffffd0cd" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/capital_u"
    android:id="@+id/u_textView"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/logoBackground"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/logoBackground"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/logoBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Center Textview in ImageView of Relative Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327367/android-center-textview-in-imageview-of-relative-layout)

Comment: post ur desired image pls..

Comment: @MSGadag that it at the top of the question except the U is actually centered! I did my best with just dragging it around to show the idea

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.spencer.app.ProfileActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#ffffd0cd"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_useless"
        android:minHeight="140dp"
        android:minWidth="140dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/u_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/logoBackground"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/logoBackground"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/logoBackground"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/logoBackground"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/logoBackground"
        android:text="@string/capital_u"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not centering a view INSIDE of something else, you're just trying to draw on top.

One possible solution would be to set the width and height of the `TextView` to be the same as the dimensions of the `ImageView`. Then, add this to your `TextView`'s XML:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

But overall, this is NOT the right way to do this sort of stuff. You'd be much better off just changing the background of your `TextView` with something like this:

```
android:background="#ffffd0cd"
```

You can also change the background to be a drawable:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_logo_background_image"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
tools:context="com.spencer.app.ProfileActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="140dp"
    android:minWidth="140dp"
    android:id="@+id/logoBackground"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:background="#ffffd0cd"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="U"
    android:id="@+id/u_textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/logoBackground"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/logoBackground"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/logoBackground" />
```

I didnot changed much but Its work. Replace your code with this it will work for you. :)